# DELETE where post_id = PEzQo82KYTLLoXw AND `PEzQo82KYTLLoXw#comment_id` random

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

I have a table that has the following example

[image]

I need to delete both but the problem is that I have only post id: "PEzQo82KYTLLoXw" as parameter, how to delete both even when it has a comment?

**post_id#comment**

`PEzQo82KYTLLoXw#comment_id`

For while this is my query

```
$p_id = "PEzQo82KYTLLoXw";
$likes = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM likes WHERE post_id = :like_p_id');
$likes->bindParam(':like_p_id',  $p_id);
$likes->execute();
```

since the comment is random, how to also delete all comments linked to it ?

```
`PEzQo82KYTLLoXw#comment_id`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a LIKE clause to match the pattern of pid

```
      $p_id = "PEzQo82KYTLLoXw";
    $likes = $pdo->prepare('DELETE 
          FROM likes WHERE post_id like
            Concat( :like_p_id,'%');
            $likes->bindParam(':like_p_id',  
       $p_id);
     $likes->execute();
```

Comment: You have errors in your code!

Comment: Syntactically maybe but I was trying to denote pattern matching via like clause updated with concat now

Comment: i am trying to select before delete, 
`SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `post_id` LIKE Concat('PEzQo82KYTLLoXw %')` selects nothing

Comment: ohh got it `SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `post_id` LIKE Concat('PEzQo82KYTLLoXw', '%')´

Comment: Yeah.. Does that help?

Comment: yeah, please update to `$likes = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM likes WHERE post_id like  Concat( :like_p_id,'%')");
$likes->bindParam(':like_p_id', $p_id);
$likes->execute();` you missed a `)` in the query so I will mark as right